# Из Apache на nginx (.htaccess)

Tags: apache, nginx, .htaccess

Разрабатываю сайты локально изначально через сборку denwer. Как известно, там стандартная сборка PHP + MySQL + Apache. Но уже на реальном сервере собрался ставить вместо Apache всеми рекомендуемый Nginx. Удалил dewner и поставил сборку Winginx (PHP + Mysql + Nginx). Очень удобно! Но! Нужно переделать под nginx (.htaccess) (В nginx я очень мало чего знаю, раньше не работал с ним).В разработке сайта использую фреймворк Codeigniter. После того как я поставил сайт на эту сборку, перестали работать роуты.Как я не пытался правильно заставить работать сайт - не получилось. Да и в интернете хорошо расписанной информации по этой теме мало.

Вот нашел сайт для конвертации из .htaccess для nginx: http://www.anilcetin.com/convert-apache-htaccess-to-nginx/

Мой .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinksOptions -IndexesDirectoryIndex index.phpRewriteEngine onRewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|public)RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(cssіjsіjpgіgifіpng)$RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-fRewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-dRewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]Options +ExecCGIAddDefaultCharset UTF-8php_value default_charset UTF-8
```

В принципе, что я хотел узнать: небольшой туториал для переезда из apache на nginx в моем случае. Заранее спасибо.

**U (nginx.conf):**

```
#user  nobody;worker_processes  1;#error_log  logs/error.log;#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;#error_log  logs/error.log  info;pid        temp/nginx.pid;events {    worker_connections  1024;}http {    include       mime.types;    default_type  application/octet-stream;    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;    sendfile        on;    #tcp_nopush     on;    #keepalive_timeout  0;    keepalive_timeout  65;    client_max_body_size 55m;    #gzip  on;    scgi_temp_path  temp/uwsgi_temp 1 2;    uwsgi_temp_path  temp/uwsgi_temp 1 2;    fastcgi_connect_timeout 1;    server {        listen   127.0.0.1:80;        root home/localhost/public_html;        index index.php index.html;        log_not_found off;        charset utf-8;        access_log  logs/access.log  main;        location ~ /\. {deny all;}        location / {            if ($host ~ ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9\-\.]+)$){                root home/$2/public_html;                access_log  logs/$2-access.log  main;            }        }        location ~ \.php$ {            if ($host ~ ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9\-\.]+)$){                root home/$2/public_html;                access_log  logs/$2-access.log  main;            }            if (!-e $document_root$document_uri){return 404;}            fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;            fastcgi_index index.php;            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;            include fastcgi_params;        }    }    server {        listen 127.0.0.1:443;        include ssl.conf;        root home/localhost/public_html;        index index.php index.html;        log_not_found off;        charset utf-8;        access_log  logs/access.log  main;        location ~ /\. {deny all;}        location / {            if ($host ~ ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9\-\.]+)$){                root home/$2/public_html;                access_log  logs/$2-access.log  main;            }        }        location ~ \.php$ {            if ($host ~ ^(www\.)?([a-z0-9\-\.]+)$){                root home/$2/public_html;                access_log  logs/$2-access.log  main;            }            if (!-e $document_root$document_uri){return 404;}            fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;            fastcgi_index index.php;            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;            include fastcgi_params;        }    }    include tools-*.conf;    include vhosts/*.conf;}
```

Answer (score 1):

[В nginx if'ы - зло](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil). Правильно будет как-то так на location'ах:

```
server {    # server_name и прочая конфигурация    charset utf-8;    # статика    location /public/ {}    location /images/ {}    location = /robots.txt {}    location ~ \.(css|js|png|gif|jpg)$ {}    # бэкенд    location ~ \.php$ {        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;        include fastcgi_params;        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/scripts$fastcgi_script_name;    }    location @backend {        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;        include fastcgi_params;        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/scripts/index.php;        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $request_uri;    }    # остальные запросы    location / {        try_files $request_uri @backend;    }}
```

Comment: Как я понял, нужно прописать это в конце файла nginx vhost ?А где написано "# server_name и прочая конфигурация" - нужно прописать server_name,root,listen...?...Просто ранее никогда не работал с nginx.

Comment: Приведите ваш полный конфиг.

Comment: Файл nginx.conf? Обновил вопрос.